# Rails Passenger & mysql Access denied for user

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

I have a rails application running on Fedora 20 against Apache & mysql (Maria db)
It worked with no issues  until a recent update to Fedora , afterwards passanger failed with this error

> Web application could not be started
>
> Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' to database 'TheDB'
>   (Mysql2::Error)

running rails from the command line using  WEBrick  works fine,  it is also possible to connect to the mysql with

**mysql -u user -h loalhost m -p**

reinstalling passenger & mysql2 gem did not help

After a few hours of tackling this I am drawing a complete blank on what else to try

I will welcome any ideas

Comment: in mysql.User what is the value in field Host for user "user" ? Does mysql -u user -h REAL_IP also works ? ( http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_bind-address )

Comment: Do you connect using a tcp/ip connection or via a UNIX socket?

Comment: @aconrad : it is working using real IP

Comment: @davidb: I am using rails defualt which is connection via port (i've added debug messages in the mysql2 adapter file to verity this)

Comment: what does it say ? select Host from mysql.user where User='user'; ?

Comment: @aconrad : the result is localhost.  As I wrote above rails will run using WEBrick  so I believe the root cause is related to either Apache or Passenger  permission or some other configuration related issue

Comment: @aconrad: You were on the right track!  I tried changing the  user to root and now I can connect!.   root has several other domains (all are versions of the loopback) so something is wrong with the less privileged  user.  Many  thanks,  if you you'll write your answer below I'd be very happy to up-vote and mark it is the accepted  answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can connect using the right username and password from command line but your scripts cannot connect using the same credentials, check the the database mysql, table user for the correct values in the column Host.

```
SELECT Host FROM mysql.user WHERE User='myusername';
```

From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connection-access.html :

> Identity checking is performed using the three user table scope
>   columns (**Host**, User, and Password). The server accepts the connection
>   only if the **Host** and **User** columns in some user table row match the
>   client **host name** and **user name** and the client supplies the password
>   specified in that row.

Check if the [sorting rules](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connection-access.html) are not affecting you :

> The server uses the **first row** that matches the **client host** name and **user name**.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the exact same issue. while setting up the ror app all the rake commands worked fine. mysql was simply accessible from linux console by simply typing "mysql" and it take to mysql console and database.yml was using root user with empty password.

Exact same setup was working on other dev instances but after spending a full day i got the solution.

When we use following configs in database.yml

```
*evelopment: &development
  adapter: mysql2
  database: development
  encoding: utf8
  username: root
  password:
  host: localhost
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock*
```

Then application tries to connect to mysql as "mysql -u root -h localhost" and in my case this command was giving following error.

```
*$mysql -u root -h 127.0.0.1
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'*
```

After adjusting root user with following, issue resolved.

```
*sudo mysql -u root
use mysql;
update user set plugin='' where User='root';
flush privileges;
exit;*
```